# Transform all child objects using recursive reduce in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, reduce

I'm trying to create a set of reducers in order to change an attribute of all objects in a nested list.

The input payload looks like the following:

```
const payload = [
  {
    name: "Peter",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Sarah",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Sophie",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Chris"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I now want to change the `name` attribute of all elements and child elements.

```
const mapJustNickname = elem => {
  return {
    ...elem,
    nickname: elem.name + "y"
  };
};
```

How do I use this map function recursively on all child elements?

I found a way to do this by putting the the recursion within the same mapping function.

```
const mapToNickname = (elem) => {
    return {
    nickname: elem.name +'y',
    children: elem.children && elem.children.map(mapToNickname)
  }
}

console.log(payload.map(mapToNickname));
```

But I'd like to have the mapping of the name separated from the recursion (for reasons of keeping the mapping functions as simple as possible) and being able to chain them later. Is it somehow possible to do this with two reducers and then chaining them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a recursive map function that maps an item, and it's children (if exists). Now you can supply the `recursiveMap` with a ever transformer function you want, and the transformer doesn't need to handle the recursive nature of the tree.

```js
const recursiveMap = childrenKey => transformer => arr => {
  const inner = (arr = []) =>
    arr.map(({ [childrenKey]: children, ...rest }) => ({
      ...transformer(rest),
      ...children && { [childrenKey]: inner(children) }
    }));
    
  return inner(arr);
};

const mapNickname = recursiveMap('children')(({ name, ...rest }) => ({
  name,
  nickname: `${name}y`,
  ...rest
}));

const payload = [{"name":"Peter","children":[{"name":"Sarah","children":[{"name":"Sophie","children":[{"name":"Chris"}]}]}]}];

const result = mapNickname(payload);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Very interesting, I quite like that! Is that in any library that you know of?

Comment: Since this uses standart map and spread, you don't need any library, but you can use any library that has a map method.

Comment: I played around with it a little more, its exactly what I had in mind. Thanks a lot for your help! There's probably no way to capsulate the map in Line 3 - 6 and move it to a separate `const` right?

Comment: You can do it easily, by removing the partial application, and having a function that always receives 3 parameters (childrenKey, transformer, arr). However, I think that the partial application is easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by rigorously defining the data structures:

```hs
data Person = Person { name :: String, nickname :: Maybe String }

data Tree a = Tree { value :: a, children :: Forest a }

type Forest a = [Tree a]

type FamilyTree = Tree Person

type FamilyForest = Forest Person
```

Now, we can create `mapTree` and `mapForest` functions:

```js
const mapTree = (mapping, { children=[], ...value }) => ({
    ...mapping(value),
    children: mapForest(mapping, children)
});

const mapForest = (mapping, forest) => forest.map(tree => mapTree(mapping, tree));

// Usage:

const payload = [
  {
    name: "Peter",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Sarah",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Sophie",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Chris"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const mapping = ({ name }) => ({ name, nickname: name + "y" });

const result = mapForest(mapping, payload);

console.log(result);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very clean solution too, really appreciate the help!